# Why am I getting Net::HTTPBadResponse with this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, faraday

I am going thru Faraday to make a request.  I use FakeWeb to stub out the request.

**faraday code**

```
  middleware =  [
  Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded,
  AirbrakeAPI::Middleware::RaiseResponseError,
  FaradayMiddleware::Mashify,
  FaradayMiddleware::ParseXml,
  AirbrakeAPI::Middleware::ScrubResponse,
  AirbrakeAPI::Middleware::RaiseServerError]

  @connection ||= Faraday.new(default_options.deep_merge(connection_options)) do |builder|
    middleware.each { |mw| builder.use *mw }
    builder.adapter :net_http
    builder.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/
```

**fakeweb code**

```
DEFAULTS = {:content_type => "application/json; charset=utf-8", :status => ["200", "OK"]}

def fixture_request(verb, url, file)
  FakeWeb.register_uri(verb, url, DEFAULTS.merge(:response => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fixtures', file)))
end

fixture_request :get, "http://example.com/notices.json", 'notices.json'
```

**notices.json file**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 05:24:04 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{
  "notices": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "projectId": 1,
      "groupId": "1696170",
      "createdAt": "2014-10-22T03:00:00.407Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "projectId": 1,
      "groupId": "1234",
      "createdAt": "2014-10-22T03:00:00.407Z"
    }
  ],
  "count": 2
}
```

The error I get:

```
# Net::HTTPBadResponse:
     #   wrong header line format
```

In the notices.json file, if I remove lines 1-4 (line 1 = HTTP/1.1 200 OK), then I still get this error:

```
# Net::HTTPBadResponse:
     #   wrong status line: "{"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `notices.json` isn't valid HTTP. Note the CRLF (new line) after the headers and before the body: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html